# How can I clear validation-on-blur errors when I use an onBlur trigger?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am developing a v-text-field that will allow simple math expressions like 1+1 to result in 2 when you either press enter or blur (lose focus) from the text field. This is my code so far.

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    :rules="rules"
    @blur="compute"
    @keydown.enter="compute"
    v-model="localValue"
    validate-on-blur
  />
</template>

<script>
import { create, all } from 'mathjs'
const math = create(all)

export default {
    name: "NumericTextField",
    props: ["value"],
    data () {
        return {
            localValue: this.value,
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value (v) {
            this.localValue = v
        },
    },
    methods: {
        compute () {
            try {
                const result = math.evaluate(this.localValue)
                this.$emit("input", result)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("compute error", e)
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        rules () {
                return [v => /^([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/.test(v) || "Must be numeric."]
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

There is one odd behavior in that when I blur the text field, by let's say tabbing away to the next text field, validate-on-blur takes effect and so does the @blur to compute the result. Validation wins this race I am left with a violation error showing up while the result quickly changes to a numeric answer which should be valid. Concretely, I type 1+1 (which is not numeric since there's a plus sign in there). When I press tab, the text box is changed to 2 (which is great) and also a validation error appears complaining about the fact that 1+1 is not numeric. That's not desired. If the result is numeric I'd like the validation to take that into account. But I don't know how to control this race condtion.

I have tried, and had success latching on to the form of the page, and explicitly revalidating all forms on the field by giving my form a ref and then calling this.$refs.myForm.validate() at the end of compute. But that makes my component not really very reusable since it needs to know about the parent form. Furthermore, it's reevaluating all form validations on blur which I think could get expensive if there are a lot of these one one page.

Is there a way to control the race condition? Or a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to prevent Vuetify's `validate-on-blur` from running first.  So here is how you can do a sneaky workaround without it.  Your template will look like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    :rules="rules"
    @blur="validate"
    @keydown.enter="validate"
    @focus="clearRules"
    @input="clearRules"
    v-model="localValue"
  />
</template>
```

Since you won't use `validate-on-blur`, you need to manually code the setting and clearing of `rules`, otherwise they'll be applied immediately on input.  Define a data property with an empty array:

```js
data() {
  return {
    rules: []
  }
},
```

The `rules` will be cleared every time the field is focused or input occurs.  All that's needed now is to run a validate method on every `blur`/`keydown` which will: 1) set the rules, and 2) compute the result:

```js
validate() {
  this.setRules();
  this.compute();
},
setRules() {
  this.rules = [v => /^([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/.test(v) || "Must be numeric."];
},
compute() {
  try {
    const result = math.evaluate(this.localValue)
    this.$emit("input", result)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("compute error", e)
  }
},
```

Here is the working demo (I used `eval` instead of your `mathjs` library):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      // ...
      rules: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.setRules();
      this.compute();
    },
    setRules() {
      this.rules = [v => /^([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+$/.test(v) || "Must be numeric."];
    },
    compute() {
      try {
        this.localValue = eval(this.localValue);
      } catch(e) {
        // console.log("compute error", e)
      }
    },
    clearRules() {
      this.rules = [];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-text-field
      :rules="rules"
      @blur="validate"
      @keydown.enter="validate"
      @focus="clearRules"
      @input="clearRules"
      v-model="localValue"
      ></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>



<!-- LIBRARIES -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Idea taken from [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3530#issuecomment-549741704) and tailored to work with `blur`.

Comment: That's pretty clever. Definitely a hack, but encapsulated enough that it's possibly the best solution for my problem. I was hoping that there would be some way to retrigger the validate on one text input after the compute was done. Maybe not though.

Comment: It already does. Even if `compute` results in a non-numeric answer, even then the validation shows up. Run the demo from the code snippet to see it in action.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I see what this code does. What I meant was that I was hoping there was a way to simply trigger the validation of a text box given the rules it has. So even when validation is done to quickly, I could simply trigger validation once more and it would be cleared up. Is there a way to just control the error state of the v-text-field without using rules? Like set it to an error state with a message manually and unset it as I see fit, and basically reimplement rules? Not that I'd necessarily want to do this over the above hack, but I'm trying to figure out all the options.

Comment: I suppose error-count and error-messages would do this actually.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right.  This [Vuetify doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs/#caveats) has a little about manual error setting:  "As any validatable Vuetify component, v-input can be set to error state using error prop".